# I can´t open my QGIS 3.22 projects

Tags: qgis-3

I have been using QGIS 3.22.10 all this year (2023). Today, none of my projects open.
The software opens, with a blank page.
Can someone explain the reason for this? Do I need to actualize the software?

Comment: How blank? Do you see the QGIS menus etc? Are you opening the projects from the File menu or double-clicking the .qgz project file? What operating system? Can you try re-installing QGIS?

Comment: What have you added recently?

Comment: Try with a new, clean user profile